# mobile friendly muti-select picklist

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

I'm iterating through a fieldset and want to display a multi-select picklist field as a standard HTML multiselect (only 1 column, ctrl+click to select multiple on desktop). The extra-wide standard salesforce multiselect is pretty wide and not mobile friendly.

I have a very manual approach I'm about to try but is anyone aware of a straightforward way to do this or an existing VF component that would handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need an HTML-only solution, and not Touch, etc, you're essentially going to want to roll your own as the current VF component for multi-select has the issue you're describing. There are a few approaches that work.

- impose your own CSS styling on the components using the !important attribute to override default SFDC styling. Takes a bunch of testing across platforms and can be labor-intensive depending on how many platforms you are targeting, but you get 100% control.
- use an existing mobile-friendly library to re-style the controls or create your own multi-select component. This also takes a bunch of work because the SFDC multi-picklist isn't going to be natively supported by the libraries out there per se; I've created components from scratch in the past that use a mobile component library (e.g. jQuery Mobile, ExtJs) with the Describe API to build out a multi-select-like control. Again, pretty labor intensive but you can create a good reusable VF component for this. jQuery Mobile is a good starting point, and [their multi-select approach](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html) looks pretty nice across most mobile devices. Again a bit of work to integrate.
- the closest I'm aware of a publicly available solution is [Abhinav Gupta's jQuery plugin for multiselect on mobile](http://www.tgerm.com/2012/01/ipad-multiselect-picklist-jquery-plugin.html). Haven't used it personally but it looks legit and he has some Youtube videos showing it in action.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this:

VF for Contact object (I handle others as well in my scenario) It handles non mulit-select picklists with just an inputField, the multi-selects are handled with an selectList

```
<!-- for contact fields -->
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!section.objectName=='Contact'}">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT($ObjectType.Contact.fields[f.fieldPath].type=='multipicklist')}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!thisContact[f.fieldPath]}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel> 
    <!-- multi-select picklists handled differently -->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields[f.fieldPath].type=='multipicklist'}"> 
        <apex:selectList value="{!section.fieldName2SelectedOptions[f.fieldPath]}" multiselect="true">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!section.fieldName2Options[f.fieldPath]}"/>                                 
        </apex:selectList>                                                      
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Theres a little bit of work done in the controller though. It has to build 2 maps.

- `map<string,list<string>> fieldName2SelectedOptions` - a list of all
  the selected picklist values for each field
- `map<string,list<SelectOption>> fieldName2Options` - a list of all
  available picklist values for each field

It builds the 1st by parsing the field values that are separated by semi-colons.
It builds the 2nd through the describe info for the field

When saving it also has to do a join on the list of selected strings by semi-colon and save it back to the field before updating the object.

There's obviously a little more to it than this since I'm dealing with multiple objects with fieldsets in my scenario but thats the jist of it! Hope its helpful to someone else.

In addition
You can directly assign the multi-value you get from the select list (comma separated value) to multi-picklist field of the object. No need to parse.

Comment: A comment was added to the end of my response 'In addition You can directly assign the multi-value you get from the select list (comma separated value) to multi-picklist field of the object. No need to parse.' are you sure thats true? It doesn't seed to be delimited by semi-colons?