# Visualforce multiselect picklist in salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, jquerymobile, salesforce1-platform

How to display visualforce multi select picklist in visual force page using jquery mobile?

Answer (score 5):

You have a number of options as listed on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14877/mobile-friendly-muti-select-picklist) post as well

- You can use this [open source component](http://www.tgerm.com/2012/01/ipad-multiselect-picklist-jquery-plugin.html) provided by Force.com MVP
  Abhinav Gupta
- Alternatively, you can use the [jQuery Mobile custom
  menu](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html#&ui-state=dialog) with `multiple="multiple"` attribute set and handle the
  appropriate logic in your controller